# Unknown bitstream filter prores_metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

When I type the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le -bsf:v prores_metadata=bt709 output.mov

I have the following error:

`Unknown bitstream filter prores_metadata`

However this bitstream filter is documented here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#prores_005fmetadata

My `ffmpeg` version is 4.1 downloaded from *Homebrew* on *macOS 10.13*.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitstream filter was added after 4.1.

Get a recent static git binary, like this one: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/macos64/static/ffmpeg-20181127-1035206-macos64-static.zip

Comment: I tried it on windows and it doesn't work. Is it possible that it's included only on macos/linux version?

Comment: Did you get the Windows 64-bit static dated build? I see it in there.

Comment: sorry my mistake it works.